# YII: how to listing and show in category

Tags: php, yii

i have source Yii Blog
http://www.yiiframework.com/demos/blog/

I make category for post
[image]

how to make action For listing posts in category in post  Controller

my relation in post model :

```
                'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Category', 'id_category'),
```

For example: 
show post in category list :

www.mysite.com/category/1

www.mysite.com/category/2

Answer (score 0):

In controller put this action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $models=Post::model->find('id_category = : id_category', [': id_category' => $_GET['id']]);

    $this->render('index',array(
        'models'=>$models,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks You but this line syntax error=>    $models=Post::model->find('id_category = : id_category', [': id_category' => $_GET['id']]);

Comment: Sorry, that is correct `$models = Post::model()->find('id_category = : id_category', [': id_category' => $_GET['id']]);`

Comment: error 500

SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': id_category LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: Sorry again(( that is correct `$models = Post::model()->find('id_category = :id_category', [':id_category' => $_GET['id']]);` A space in `: id_category`, it is error.

Answer (score 0):

i used this code

```
public function actionCategorylist()
{
$models = Post::model()->find('id_category = : id_category', [': id_category' => $_GET['id']]);
    $this->render('index',array(
        'models'=>$models,
    ));
}
```

And check adress
www.mysite.com/post/Categorylist/id/1

But error 500

***SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': id_category LIMIT 1' at line 1***